# Task.Start .NET CORE Unable to load DLL combase.dll error Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have some code that utilizes basic C# Task objects.  However, when developing on a Windows 7 machine, attempting to run `Task.Start();` results in:

> Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
>
> Additional Information:  Unable to load DLL 'combase.dll': the specified module could not be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

When running this code on a windows 10 dev machine everything works fine.

In doing research for a version of combase.dll for windows 7 I have so far come up blank.

Has anyone else had this error before and if so, how did you work around it?

Comment: I think your windows 7 installation is missing some binaries (dlls), in particular the one you mentionned.

I would try to repair the windows installation to copy any missing dependencies

[Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

Comment: Running the utility reports all is fine and nothing wrong.  File still does not exist.  Appears that win 7 users *may* have the file if they install Office manually (though 2010 install does not have the file).  

Still cannot find a copy to install on my dev box.  Have noted that this is a deficiency in CORE and to avoid having our software explode on a user running win 7, switched over to Func calls for now.

Comment: I have this issue as well all of a sudden after upgrade to 1.1.  Been battling it for a few days with no solution.  If I find one will put it here.

Comment: Honestly installing Win 10 now to get by this. Put out to Twitter for others to see.

Comment: I wanted to avoid installing Win 10 because this issue means that Win 7 users are going to have a bad time and I don't want to develop something that currently has no resolution for Win 7 users.

Comment: @auticus Can you run the sample I posted in the answer see if it work on your Win 7 machine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from compatibility chart posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-standard) the minimum supported windows version is 8.0 and 10 for the newer versions of the netstandard framework and therefore of dotnet core.

Windows 7 is simply not supported and therefore dotnet core won't run. I am not saying there are no work-arounds but I wouldn't recommend hosting dotnet core code on windows 7 for production purposes.

Windows 7 is legacy already since the mainstream support ended 2 years ago (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet) so don't expect dotnet core to become compatible to it at any point. If you have to support windows 7 I'm afraid you will have to rely on the classic dotnet framework.

Comment: This is definitely the answer OP. Windows 7 is just not supported by the .NET Core team.

Comment: Thanks.  This information was not present at the time I posted the question last year (or was not able to be found anywhere when we searched for it).  The closest we got to an answer was a blog from the dotnet core devs saying it wasn't done yet, so we abandoned that project and turned to a different architecture.